# Installing jdevstudio in Ubuntu

Tags: 12.10, install-from-source

I'm trying to install jdevstudio from Oracle on Ubuntu 12.10. I have downloaded a file with `.bin` extension. Unfortunately neither of the two provided methods (using terminal or setting the permission) works for me. I have placed the file in home folder but again nothing happens. What should I do?

p.s. when using `./jdevstudio11123isntall.bin` command, terminal responds with

```
unable to execute [filename] no such file or directory.
```

Comment: @vasa1 sorry but what do you mean by fix? and how? don't you mean download it again?

Comment: @vasa1 thanks. seems I need to rest my eyes for a while and pay more attention. I will check it again as soon as I'm on Ubuntu again.

Comment: @vasa1 the problem persists with the message: "bash: ./jdevstudio11123install.bin: No such file or directory", I should mention that I have downloaded a Windows version of the software and it works well on the platform.

Answer (score 0):

Well you are supposed to do  one more thing before that.

`chmod +x yourfilename.bin`
and then
`./filename.bin`

If  you have only one `.bin` file in that, then you need not worry about its name. You can run it after `chmod +x` command with `./*.bin`.

I mean

```
chmod +x *.bin
./*.bin
```

Comment: I have followed the steps as I mentioned in the question. but still nothing happens.

Comment: paste the log please

Comment: It's all in question.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

On a terminal run the following:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

### Cause

Installation Manger is a 32-bit application and requires 32-bit versions of operating system libraries. These libraries are not installed on Ubuntu 64-bit by default.

### Source

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21438771